# NS записи и идентификация владельца

Tags: ns

Есть beget.ru на котором зарегистрирован домен. Есть другой хостинг с VPS, который выдал 2 своих NS записи, которые были прописаны на beget.ru.

Домен прописался и теперь работает отлично с VPS хостинга. На сколько я понимаю, NS записи совсем не уникальны. Но при этом домен привязался именно к нужному аккаунту на хостинге и работает так, как прописано в виртуальных хостах.

Как хостинг провайдер(любой) определяет к какому аккаунту нужно привязать домен?
Ещё раз, никакой информации о том, что данный домен должен быть привязан, на хостинге не указывалось, указывались только 2 записи NS на бегете. Вот они:

ns1.vps-dns.info

ns2.vps-dns.info

или ns записи по определению уникальны для абсолютно каждого аккаунта на хостинге у любого провайдера?

Comment: Я кажется понимаю, что вы спрашиваете. Но внесите ясность. Допустим, есть DNS `ns*vps-dns.info`, на который вы делегировали с бегета. И который общий для всех пользователей VDS хостинга. Ваш вопрос в том, как VDS определяет, какие записи, например A-записи, следует внести, ведь у него может быть тысячи клиентов? Есть так, то... никак! У меня были случаи, когда я делегировал домены на ns сервера хостера, в DNS я ничего не прописывал, и какой-то умелец прописал там свои записи, и начали открываться его сайты. Пришлось писать в поддержку, и доказывать, что я это я.

Comment: А на яндекс DNS есть процедура подтверждения против этого.

Answer (score 1):

> никакой информации о том, что данный домен должен быть привязан, на хостинге не указывалось

так не бывает. На хостинге указывается, какой домен будет прослушиваться. И на ns*.vps-dns.info вносится запись о соответствии вашего домена и IP сайта

Браузер получает цепочку из DNS вашдомен.ru->ns*.vps-dns.info->aa.bb.cc.dd